# OpenID login with google and grabbing the user form input with a session variable with PHP?

Tags: php, forms, session, openid

I'm trying to validate a user with *LightOpenID* and what I also need is to get their profile name but I'm having trouble getting a session variable `$_SESSION['profile']` to get the form post `$_POST['profile']` to store the information before the page is redirected to google. I'm not sure if this is the way to go about this but I can't think of any other way to tie a user to my database besides doing this. Here's the code

```
<?php

session_start(); 
# Logging in with Google accounts requires setting special identity, so this example shows how to do it.
require 'openid.php';
try 
{       
    $openid = new LightOpenID('http://www.some_site.com');
    if(!$openid->mode) {
        if(isset($_GET['login'])) 
        {          
            $_SESSION['profile'] = $_POST['profile'];
            $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
            header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
        }
?>
<form action="?login" method="post">
        <table border="0"> 
         <tr><td colspan=2><h1>Login</h1></td></tr> 
         <tr><td>Username:</td><td> 
             <input type="text" name="profile" maxlength="40"> 
         </td></tr>             
        </table> 
    <button>Login with Google</button>
</form>
<?php
    } 
    elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') 
    {
        echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
    } 
    else 
    {

        echo    $_SESSION['profile'];      
        echo 'User ' . ($openid->validate() ? $openid->identity .  ' has ' : 'has not ') . 'logged in.';          
    }
} 
catch(ErrorException $e) 
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Doesn't show email after login though.

```
<?php
require 'openid.php';
$openid = new LightOpenID('http://www.some_site.com'); 

if (!$openid->mode) {
   $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
   $openid->required = array('contact/email');
   header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
} else {
   if ($openid->validate()) {
      $attributes = $openid->getAttributes();
      $google_email = $attributes['contact/email'];
      echo $google_email."<br />";
      echo "<pre>" . print_r($_GET, true) . "</pre>";
      //header("Location: " . SITEURL);
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
<?php
if (!$openid->mode) {
   $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
   $openid->required = array('contact/email');
   header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
} else {
   if ($openid->validate()) {
      $attributes = $openid->getAttributes();
      $google_email = $attributes['contact/email'];
      echo $google_email."<br />";
      echo "<pre>" . print_r($_GET, true) . "</pre>";
      //header("Location: " . SITEURL);
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do I use the same form as mine above and why did you conment out the header line?

Comment: Just for testing what you get in $_GET variable.

Comment: It's not printing the google email though. I reposted your code above As tested.

Comment: The email does exist in the url after validation for some reason but I'm not sure how to retrieve it.

Comment: The code also doesn't return true for the part where `$openid->validate()`.